# Dynamically load jade templates

Tags: view, include, express, pug

I'm working on a small documentation website and the content is stored in files. For instance I have two files `chapter1.jade` and `chapter2.jade` in a `module1/` directory.

I'd like to read the `module1/` directory and dynamically include all the `chapterX.jade` files in it.

I tried to have do `directory = fs.readDirSync('module1/')` and then in my view:

```
each item in directory
  include item
```

But jade include doesn't support dynamic values (even `include #{item}) doesn't work. Do you have any idea how I could implement this ?

EDIT: I'd like to generate some code under the `each` loop (anchor for easy linking) so the solution would preferabily be in the view. I could obviously manually add the anchor in the included files but it is not ideal.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the short version of what I've done to make it work. It uses the [jade Public API](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#public-api).

```js
var directory = __dirname+'/views/bla/'
  , files
  , renderedHTML = '';

if( !fs.existsSync(directory) ) {
  // directory doesn't exist, in my case I want a 404
  return res.status(404).send('404 Not found');
}

// get files in the directory
files = fs.readdirSync(directory);

files.forEach(function(file) {
  var template = jade.compile(fs.readFileSync(directory+file, 'utf8'));

  // some templating
  renderedHTML += '<section><a id="'+file+'" name="'+file+'" class="anchor">&nbsp;</a>'+template()+'</section>';
});

// render the actual view and pass it the pre rendered views
res.render('view', { 
  title: 'View',
  files: files,
  html: renderedHTML
})
```

And the view just renders the html variable unescaped:

```
div(class="component-doc-wrap")
  !{html}
```

Comment: mmh, not exactly. I'd just use jade myself to have some kind of cache control, I think

Comment: I'm pretty new to Express/Jade, could you give me an example? Thanks!

Comment: for-each-ing the array of files, then using jade.renderFile() to append it to a string, and render that string

Comment: Thanks for pointing the direction. Jade Public API changed though: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7294279/999540
jade.renderFile() is now jade.compile()

Answer (score 0):

As @user1737909 say, that's not possible using just jade.

The best way to do this (tho) is building a little **<s>Express Dynamic (view) Helpers</s>**

**DEPECATED IN EXPRESS 3.XX**

<s>Check these:  [Jade - way to add dynamic includes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394501/jade-way-to-add-dynamic-includes)</s>

Comment: I did research before asking and saw this post. Though the link to the documentation is dead and it looks like dynamic helpers are a feature of the version 2. I'm using the latest Express 3.

Comment: yep, dynamic includes were removed

Comment: then we are out of luck @kalema. Edited

Answer (score 0):

in addition to kalemas answer you can also write your includes to a file which is included in jade.

in this example I write my includes to include_all.jade. This file is included in a jade file.

If it does not work, check the path ;-)

e.g.
in your app.js

```
var includes = "path/to/include1\n";
includes += "path/to/include2";
...
incPath = "path/to/include_all.jade";

fs.open(incPath,'w',function(err,fd){
if(err){
    throw 'error open file: ' + incPath +" "+ err;
}

var buffer = new Buffer(includes);
 fs.write(fd,buffer,0,buffer.length,null,function(err){
    if (err) 
        throw 'error writing file: ' +err;
    fs.close(fd,function(){
        console.log('file written ' + incPath);
    });
 });
});
```

in your jade file

```
include path/to/include_all.jade
```